# What is N.D.E. short hand for?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Feel free to delete this question if it is at the wrong place. I am reading a mathematics text in French, which wrote, in the footnote:

"N.D.E:..."

What does that mean?

I also took a screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's a shorthand for *[Note de l’éditeur](http://www.guide-typographie.com/abreviations.htm)* (editor's note) and not "Near Death Experience" ;-)

Note that the more common *NDLR* for *Note de la rédaction* has essentially the same meaning.